# Android Lollipop: Where to find code of "API Demos" app preinstalled in the Android Lollipop Nexus 5 emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-5.0-lollipop

I have just installed Android 5 on Android studio and Made my first run on an emulator. I've found "API Demos" app really interesting and I would like to find the code. I'm talking about this app:[image]

Somebody knows where I can find it?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Check : https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-5.0.html

Comment: error occurs when build in android studio,packages like 'com.google.android.* cannot found',did you have the problam?

Answer (score 0):

Go to where your SDK is installed samples/android-X/ApiDemo

For example :-sdk\samples\android-19\legacy\ApiDemos.
In that you can get the source code

Comment: There are no samples for the SDK 21

Answer (score 0):

Try to find this path :

Finder --> go --> go to folder and enter : `~/Library/Android/sdk/samples`

pick an android level, on `android-8` you will find the `ApiDemos` on the main directory, but for `android-22` you have to find `legacy` and then pick the `ApiDemos`

be sure that the sdk is installed with android sdk manager

enjoy

Answer (score 0):

In latest versions of the SDK they are placing some samples in the following location:

**$sdk_dir/sources/android-19/com/example/...**

Depending on your SDK version you will find different samples. The Api Demos can be downloaded from here:

**https://github.com/android/platform_development/tree/master/samples**

Also is interesting to check for other APIs and services samples here:

https://github.com/googlesamples